# Flutter: after rotate widget inside stack, when changing the position it is move wrong direction

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-positioned

i try to rotate the widget and then try to move around, it moves into different direction.

I'm realize, I need another calculation to normalize the position when its move, with condition rotate more than zero , but I don't know how, if anyone can help, thank you
this is my code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  return runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: const TestingDesign2(),
    );
  }
}

class TestingDesign2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestingDesign2({super.key});

  @override
  State<TestingDesign2> createState() => _TestingDesign2State();
}

class _TestingDesign2State extends State<TestingDesign2> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Testing")),
        body: Container(
          color: Colors.blueAccent.withOpacity(0.5),
          child: Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            // clipBehavior: Clip.none,
            children: [ItemTesting()],
          ),
        ));
  }
}

class ItemTesting extends StatefulWidget {
  const ItemTesting({super.key});

  @override
  State<ItemTesting> createState() => _ItemTestingState();
}

class _ItemTestingState extends State<ItemTesting> {
  double rotation = 0;
  Size size = Size(300, 300);
  Offset position = Offset(10, 10);
  double offsetAngle = 0;
  bool isRotate = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _Item();
  }

  Widget _Item() {
    return Positioned(
      left: position.dx,
      top: position.dy,
      child: Transform.rotate(
        angle: rotation,
        child: SizedBox(
          height: size.height,
          width: size.width,
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              GestureDetector(
                onPanStart: onPanStart,
                onPanUpdate: onPanUpdate,
                onPanEnd: (details) {
                  isRotate = false;
                },
                onPanCancel: () {
                  isRotate = false;
                },
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  height: size.height,
                  width: size.width,
                ),
              ),
              IgnorePointer(
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                  child: ClipOval(
                      child: Container(
                    height: 25,
                    width: 25,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  )),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  onPanStart(details) {
    Offset centerOfGestureDetector = Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);
    final touchPositionFromCenter =
        details.localPosition - centerOfGestureDetector;
    offsetAngle = touchPositionFromCenter.direction - rotation;
    // top right
    if (details.localPosition.dx > (size.width - 25) &&
        details.localPosition.dy <= 25) {
      isRotate = true;
    }
  }

  onPanUpdate(details) {
    if (isRotate) {
      Offset centerOfGestureDetector = Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);
      final touchPositionFromCenter =
          details.localPosition - centerOfGestureDetector;
      // print(touchPositionFromCenter.direction * 180 / math.pi);

      rotation = touchPositionFromCenter.direction - offsetAngle;
    } else {
      position = new Offset(
          position.dx + details.delta.dx, position.dy + details.delta.dy);
    }
    setState(() {});
  }
}
```

[image]

https://dartpad.dev/?id=1403cd7c7a121a7b26d6b6c3ab422cf0

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by " with condition rotate more than zero?" not able to catch this point. Also i didn't notice in the Dartpad link

Comment: @SankethB.K the point is, after rotate the widget and then try to move around, it moves into different direction. after rotate means angle not zero anymore, have you try rotate before move the widget?

Comment: Understood, i'll look into it

Comment: Couldn't solve it, seems like there is a package for it, can you try it https://github.com/PratikKargathra/floating-widget/blob/main/drs_widget_code.dart

Comment: @SankethB.K alright, thanks, already found my answer. the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I managed to make a widget that can be rotated and moved without moving in the wrong direction after rotated.

this is the code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  return runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: const TestingDesign2(),
    );
  }
}



class TestingDesign2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestingDesign2({super.key});

  @override
  State<TestingDesign2> createState() => _TestingDesign2State();
}

class _TestingDesign2State extends State<TestingDesign2> {
  Size size = Size(200, 200);

  var keyItem = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Testing design 2")),
        body: Container(
          color: Colors.blueAccent.withOpacity(0.5),
          // key: keyContainer,
          child: Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            // clipBehavior: Clip.none,
            children: [ItemTesting(key: keyItem, keyItem: keyItem)],
          ),
        ));
  }
}

class ItemTesting extends StatefulWidget {
  var keyItem;
  ItemTesting({super.key, required this.keyItem});

  @override
  State<ItemTesting> createState() => _ItemTestingState();
}

class _ItemTestingState extends State<ItemTesting> {
  double rotation = 0;
  Size size = Size(300, 300);
  Offset position = Offset(10, 10);
  double offsetAngle = 0;
  bool isRotate = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _Item();
  }

  Widget _Item() {
    return Positioned(
      left: position.dx,
      top: position.dy,
      child: Transform.rotate(
        angle: rotation,
        child: SizedBox(
          height: size.height,
          width: size.width,
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              GestureDetector(
                onPanStart: onPanStart,
                onPanUpdate: onPanUpdate,
                behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
                onPanEnd: (details) {
                  isRotate = false;
                },
                onPanCancel: () {
                  isRotate = false;
                },
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  height: size.height,
                  width: size.width,
                ),
              ),
              IgnorePointer(
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                  child: ClipOval(
                      child: Container(
                    height: 25,
                    width: 25,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  )),
                ),
              ),
         
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  

  var touchPosition = Offset.zero;
  onPanStart(DragStartDetails details) {
    Offset centerOfGestureDetector = Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);
    final touchPositionFromCenter =
        details.localPosition - centerOfGestureDetector;
    offsetAngle = touchPositionFromCenter.direction - rotation;

    final RenderBox referenceBox =
        widget.keyItem.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    var x = referenceBox.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);

    touchPosition = Offset(x.dx, x.dy + 55);
    // top right
    if (details.localPosition.dx > (size.width - 25) &&
        details.localPosition.dy <= 25) {
      isRotate = true;
    }
  }

  onPanUpdate(DragUpdateDetails details) {
    if (isRotate) {
      Offset centerOfGestureDetector = Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);
      final touchPositionFromCenter =
          details.localPosition - centerOfGestureDetector;

      rotation = touchPositionFromCenter.direction - offsetAngle;
    } else {
      var positionG = position + details.globalPosition;
      var positiong2 = positionG - touchPosition;
      position = (positiong2 - position);
    }
    setState(() {});
  }
}
```